# Android: How to Spawn Several Loaders

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android app. I am using a Custom extension of AsyncTaskLoader to retrieve a JSON Array of elements from a website. Data are correctly retrieved and parsed.

Now for each object of such array I need to spawn a Loader which is aimedt at retrieving its detailed description (another URL). I have implemented such Loader but I don't know where it should be spawned.

Basically my confusion is due to the fact that the onCreateLoader method implemented by the Fragment receiving the Loaders' results (LoaderCallBacks) is supposed to return only one Loader.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically my confusion is due to the fact that the onCreateLoader
>   method implemented by the Fragment receiving the Loaders' results
>   (LoaderCallBacks) is supposed to return only one Loader.

it is almost true. The `onCreateLoader`'s signature is

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
```

you can use the first argument to spawn different loader. Of course, you have to use  `initLoader`/`restartLoader`, a number of times equal to the number of loader to spawn, each with a different `id`

Comment: Do you mean the returned loader is not actually used ?

Comment: you can return a different loader for each id